# Monitor if Perfmon counter sets are running

Tags: windows, wmi, perfmon

We have an issue where occasionally over time, a Perfmon counter set will stop.  We are looking for a way to monitor if a particular counter set is running, does anyone know of a way to do this?  We use Nagios for basic alerting but we have another monitoring tool that can run executable vbscrips, batch files, wmi queries, ect.

Does anyone have a way to verify if a perfmon set is running or stopped?  We'd rather not have to audit 120 servers manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for a way to check if a PerfMon Counter is running, have you checked into [Logman](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490956.aspx)? A simple `logman query` will show you the status of all of the counters on a system.

However, if you want to take the next step and automatically restart stopped counters, you might find this handy:

```
@echo off
set COUNTER_LIST=("LogA" "LogB" "SoForth")
for %%i in %COUNTER_LIST% do logman start %%i
```

That's a simple .bat script which will automatically restart all PerfMon Counters named in COUNTER_LIST. If a counter is already running, `logman start` delightfully does nothing.